# Jquery get all contents of tag including other tags

Tags: jquery, html, string

Lets say i have the following code:

```
<p>
hello, how are you today, <a href="sfdjo.php">John</a>?
</p>
```

Is there a way to retrieve all of the text inside so that i have a string that reads:

```
'hello, how are you today, <a href="sfdjo.php">John</a>?'
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: The jQuery API documentation is pretty good. Sounds like you're looking for this: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Assuming you outer container had an ID or class name that you can reference, then this is simple using html() method like this:

```
var containedHTML = $('#container').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string by using

```
var containedHTML = $('p').html();
```

If you have more than one p-tag in you HTML the will be appended in the result.

So the best would be to give your p-tag an id and request the text inside over this id.

```
<p id="example">
    Text
</p>
```

The following JavaScript will return your text:

```
var containedHTML = $('#example').html();
```